# What is the math behind FromToRotation? Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, quaternions

I'm trying to understand quaternions better, but I don't know how the math behind FromToRotation works. I tried looking this up but couldn't find any results.

Comment: http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/09/18/beautiful-maths-quaternion-from-vectors

Answer (score 2):

You may know that a rotation can be represented by a quaternion of the following form:

```
cos (phi / 2)
sin (phi / 2) * axis.x
sin (phi / 2) * axis.y
sin (phi / 2) * axis.z
```

`axis` is the rotation axis and `phi` is the rotation angle. These are the two measures you need to define your quaternion.

There are multiple rotations that map a vector `from` to another vector `to`. The shortest rotation is the one where the axis is perpendicular to both of the vectors. Hence, the axis is:

```
axis = normalize(from x to)
```

`x` denotes the cross product.

And the angle is the angle between the two vectors:

```
phi = acos(dot(from, to) / (norm(from) * norm(to))
```

`norm` is the vector norm or vector length.

With these values, you can then calculate the quaternion.

Comment: As far as I know, this solution will not work for an opposite vectors.